# Best way to initialize final field in an abstract class

Tags: java, javafx

I have in mind two ways to initialize a final field in an abstract class and I have to pick the most elegant, correct and understandable for other developers way. There will be at least 10 implementations of my abstract class. Any ideas on which one should I choose?

First way:

```
public sealed abstract class GuiComponent permits DummyComponent {

    private final Node internalNode;

    //------Constructor

    protected GuiComponent() {
        internalNode = Objects.requireNonNull(initInternalNode());
    }

    //------Protected

    protected abstract Node initInternalNode();

    protected final Node getInternalNode() {
        return internalNode; //subclasses will use this
    }

}

public final class DummyComponent extends GuiComponent {

    @Override
    protected Node initInternalNode() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        //some Node preparation
        return hbox;
    }

}
```

Second way:

```
public sealed abstract class GuiComponent permits DummyComponent {

    private final Node internalNode;

    //------Constructor

    protected GuiComponent(Node internalNode) {
        this.internalNode = Objects.requireNonNull(internalNode);
    }

    //------Protected

    protected final Node getInternalNode() {
        return internalNode; //subclasses will use this
    }

}

public final class DummyComponent extends GuiComponent {

    //------Constructor

    public DummyComponent() {
        super(initInternalNode());
    }

    //------Private

    private static Node initInternalNode() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        //...
        return hBox;
    }

}
```

Comment: `initInternalNode()` is invoked as part of the constructor so there is no context (since in the middle of constructing the instance), so using this approach is limiting.  For example, there is no context available to pass to `HBox` (if that is ever needed).

Comment: @AndrewS Not sure, but you saying "context" makes me think you're talking about Android. This question is regarding JavaFX, which has no built-in, explicit notion of context.

Comment: By context I meant any data `initInternalNode()` might need to decide how to create a `Node`.  Since `initInternalNode()` is called during object construction in the base class none of the fields in the sub-class would be initialized yet, e.g., no context.

Comment: In general, it is not good practice for a constructor to invoke an overridable method, primarily for the reasons explained by @AndrewS. (This is item 17 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java".)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the second approach is better. The reason being that the `GuiComponent` constructor requests a `Node`, so it is easier to understand that a `Node` is in fact needed. This makes it explicit, while the other approach makes it implicit because unless you see `GuiComponent` code, you have no way to know that `getInternalNode()` method will be called in `GuiComponent` constructor. You can even say that it is a side-effect of this constructor, as we all know side-effects are usually better avoided in software development.